# How to access a USB connected phone via perl

Tags: android, windows, perl

When I connect my android phone via USB to my PC with Windows 10, it shows up as `This PC\SAMSUNG-SM-G925A\Phone` in the browser. However, I'm not able to access the directories on the device with that string. Does anyone know what directory should I use? I have Windows based ActivePerl. For starters, is there a drive letter (if so, how can I find out) that points to the root directory on that phone? Thx!

Comment: Probably want to look at using some MTP library

Comment: As far as I know, there is no drive/directory path. It's more like a explorer plugin adding an icon and trying to behave like a folder without being one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around by copying the files (manually) to a tmp directory on C: drive and process it from there. Not elegant, but serves the purpose for now.